# Derived class thinks my base class got deleted

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I tried to make a derived WinForm class, but I have an issue: when I try to create my DerivedClass (via Add > New element > Derived Form), **Visual studio tells me that the object does not exist**

I'm sure the object at stake is BaseForm because I get the `Setting Error` message shows in the console. (my guess is because the `Close()`function is called )

```cs
public partial class BaseForm : Form
{
    Port port;

    public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        port = new Port();
        if (port.Port_Setting() != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting Error");
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

For now, BaseForm is empty, just a form with no component added.

The only part used of my `Port` class so far is this, just initializing it for further use:

```cs
class Port
{
    protected SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
    public int Port_Setting()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Setting port");
        if (sp.IsOpen)
        {
            sp.Close();
        }

        sp.BaudRate = 38400;
        sp.DataBits = 8;
        sp.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
        sp.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
        sp.PortName = "COM3";

        bool Error = false;
        try
        {
            sp.Open();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { Error = true; }
        catch (ArgumentException) { Error = true; }
        catch (System.IO.IOException) { Error = true; }
        if (Error)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried putting Close() in comments and I got the same results, also why would it launch the function upon creating the class and not on compilation ?

Comment: My issue is that I cannot generate a derived class because of an undetermined reason.
Why would my functions be called while I generate the class and not compile it?

Also, sorry about the terminology, I'm not so good at english and new to C#
@yunnosch I just want to get better at asking questions here, it's not self-evident

Comment: @Prim I think you are very confused about how WinForms works, and it is difficult know how to help you more specifically because the information you have provided doesn't explain what you are trying to do and why you think the behaviour you are seeing is wrong. I can say that 1) the issue you are seeing is nothing to do with access modifiers 2) writing code that interacts with a closed form will not work 3) this is also nothing to do with compilation, because if the code didn't compile, then you wouldn't be able to run the application.

Comment: Hopefully some documentation may explain better for you: [access modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers) explains what these do and do not do - they are only relevant on compilation, not at runtime - [Order of events in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/desktop/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) explains the life cycle of a form and should explain why `Close()`ing a form is the wrong thing to do if you want to interact with it

Comment: I know I should only call `Close()` at the end of the usage of my form, but why is it called on generating the code?

Comment: @Prim what do you mean by "generating the code"?

Comment: Generating the derived class via the Visual Studio's interface (Add > New Element>Derived Form)

Comment: This question is being discussed on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408834).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Generating the derived class via the Visual Studio's interface (Add >
> New Element>Derived Form) –

Aha now things are getting more clear to me.

When you derive a form in Visual Studio, and you open the derived form in the designer, some code on the base form (the parent where you inherited from) will be executed.

I don't know all methods from the top of my head, but I believe that the `load` event for example will be executed in the base form when you load the inherited form in the designer at design time.

This is not a flaw from VS, this is by design. The idea is that when you create a custom user control, the code in the user control can also be executed in design time. And inheriting a form from another is somewhat the same thing for the designer.

What you can do to solve this is check in the code of the base form if you are on design time or not.

I have done this by adding this method on my base form:

```
 protected bool IsInDesignMode
 {
     get { return DesignMode || LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime; }
 }
```

you can use it like this

```
    private void FormBase_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsInDesignMode == false)
        {
            // write code here that should only run at runtime
        }
    }
```